# Java 8: efficiently put values from List to the Map

Tags: java, java-8

For example, I have a following code:

```
Map<Student, Integer> rating = new HashMap<>();
...
for (Student student : studentsList) {
    rating.put(student, student.getRate());
}
```

#### Can I do the it more efficient using Java 8 tools?

---

I already tried Java8's `forEach` method:

```
studentsList.forEach(s -> rating.put(s, s.getRate()));
```

But it seems that it is more expensive. Tests of putting 1M students to the `rating` map for both methods show degradation of performance on 10% if we switch to `forEach` method (Standart forEach: **250 ms**, Java8's forEach: **270 ms**)

**UPD:** Per *Paul Boddington*'s proposal, I tried this:

```
studentsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, Student::getRate))
```

The result is the least effective among methods above.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: The idiomatic java 8 way is `studentsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, Student::getRate))`. You are not recommended to use `forEach` in this way.

Comment: Why using `Collectors` is better then `forEach`?

Comment: @BogdanKobylinsky The advice is from Oracle, not me. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/moocjdk8/documents/week3/lesson-3-3.pdf  Your update about performance is likely to be meaningless without a proper benchmark. However, I suspect your original `for` loop is the most efficient.

Comment: In this particular scenario, using a Map does not make any sense. Just use a set of Students and get the rate from the objects directly. Of course, if calculating the rate is a complex calculation, then it's a different matter, but then the overhead from the way you create the map should not really matter.